# BadImageFormatException

Tags: badimageformatexception

I have VS 2008 on Win 7 Professional 64bit system and database is Oracle 11g r2 installed on the same machine.

In Data Source Configuration Wizard --> New Connection
Data Source: Oracle Database (Oracle Client)
When I click Test Connection after entering Service name, username, and password I get the following error:

Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.
This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

-- I have no oracle client installed because there is no need in this case, I have the same setup on my laptop Win 7 32bit Oracle 11g r2 32bit and everything is working fine.

Please let let me know if you guys have solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your question how much you understand about this. Since no one has proffered an answer for 18 days I'll put in my $.02 worth. You are running under a 64 bit application so it wants to load a 64 bit .DLL. I don't know anything about Oracle but I would guess the client .dlls are written in an unmanaged environment and can't support the "any CPU" concept that a managed application does. You have a couple of options.
1. Load the 64 bit version of the Oracele client .DLLs on your 64 bit laptop if they exist.
2. Don't use the test connection feature of the wizard. You can target the app you are building for a 32 bit machine and when you app runs you won't have this problem ([see this blog post](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2011/07/badimageformatexception-when-64-meets.html) for some details on targeting)

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 is a x86 application, but when you are trying to set up a new Connection Data Source, you are using a x64 driver.

You could prove that using a tool like procmon.exe. If you do, you may notice that after starting the Test Connection process, it will try to load some x64 drivers, hence the BadImageFormatException.

The solution is to install the x86 drivers required by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup PlatformTarget in your projects build properties and it should work.